# split string with comma operator into arrraylist

Tags: java, split

I have a string

```
 String strNumbers = "One,Two,Three,Four,Five";
```

O want to split this string and produce

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
```

Help me out please.

I am using following code

```
    String strNumbers = "One,Two,Three,Four,Five";

    //split the string using split method of String class
    String[] numbers = strNumbers.split(",");

    //create new ArrayList object
    ArrayList<String> aListNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();

    //add individual numbers to the ArrayLists
    for(int i=0; i< numbers.length; i++){
        aListNumbers.add(numbers[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell us what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: this code is give me     String converted to ArrayList: [One, Two, Three, Four, Five]

Comment: ? Again, what is wrong with your code? Please ask clear questions if possible.

Comment: @NitinSharma - and that exactly is what you are asking for!  So I don't see what your real question is.  Are you really just asking how to **format** the output?

Comment: my code is not give me my expected answer , this code give me [One, Two, Three, Four, Five] but i want when comma operator occurs the string print next line

Comment: @NitinSharma: A trivial answer is to just use a for loop to print it out. Have you tried this?

Comment: @NitinSharma -  ` String[] numbers = strNumbers.split(",");` here you have split it and now you can access numbers like `numbers[0], numbers[1],... `
ex. print it in console - for(String number : numbers){
        System.out.println(number);
    } 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> aListNumbers = new ArrayList<String>(
    Arrays.asList(strNumbers.split(","));
```

`split` gives you an array.  `Arrays.asList` wraps a list around an array.
If you really need an `ArrayList`, you can then use its `ArrayList(Collection)` copy constructor.

Comment: I don't see what that this solves.  Your code and the OP's code will produce the same outcome.  Shouldn't you wait until you know what the OP is asking?

Comment: This is right but do not spoonfeed, you are giving answer rather than helping out that person in his code.

Comment: @yogeshprajapati, why not?  It isn't homework.  He's asking if there are more convenient APIs for what he's doing and I show them by example.

Comment: @TimPote, Why wait when I've got a pretty good idea what they're asking?  If I'm wrong and the OP isn't asking for suggestions on how to use core library APIs to simplify their code, then they'll clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're just printing out the `ArrayList` object.  You need to iterate *through* the `ArrayList` and print out the `String` values it contains.  You can do this with `System.out.println`, which will automatically put a new line after each value it prints.

```
for (String number : aListNumbers) {
  System.out.println(number);
}
```